# Aws Lambda TestTool Throws Exception in GetPreferenceDirectory

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am running a .net 6 lambda and when trying to use the Lambda TestTool it's throwing an unhandled exception in Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.LocalLambdaOptions.GetPreferenceDirectory(bool createIfNotExist) in LocalLambdaOptions.cs, line 66

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.LocalLambdaOptions.GetPreferenceDirectory(bool createIfNotExist) in LocalLambdaOptions.cs
Amazon.Lambda.TestTool.BlazorTester.Pages.Index.OnInitialized() in Index.razor
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
```

It's using the 0.13.1 version of the TestTool.  Any ideas?

I used the Lambda Empty Function and I have no launchsettings.json file.

Comment: Can update your question with the template that you used to create your lambda function? Also, include the `launchSettings.json` file content.

Comment: launchSettings is created by default if we create an empty lambda function in Visual Studio using the AWS Toolkit extension. In your case, I assume you might have created a function using a command line or a different method/IDE. Btw, here is the doc link for the lambda mock took: https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/master/Tools/LambdaTestTool; Make sure you followed the steps that are mentioned in the doc to setup the mock tool in local machine.